# Limit GitHub action workflow concurrency on push and pull_request?

Tags: github, github-actions

I would like to limit concurrency to one run for my workflow:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'foo/**'
  push:
    paths:
      - 'foo/**' 

concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.run_id }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

However, I found out that for `push` `head_ref` is empty and `run_id` is always unique (as described here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-a-fallback-value)

How I can create a concurrency key that will be constant across `pull_request` and `push` events?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this configuration:

```yaml
concurrency:
  group: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }} 
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

This will set the group always to the `<branch-name>`. The trick is that `github.head_ref` is only set when the workflow was triggered by a `pull_request` and it contains the value of the source branch of the PR.

[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ysfaran/concurrency-push-pull-request-test/) (especially look at `Actions` tab to see an example of cancelled workflow)

Comment: I tried this as well. Yet still, I get duplicated jobs/workflow runs.

Comment: @pixel I think you misunderstood the functionality of `concurrency`. If you look into the logs of the workflow step `Echo variables` in my sample repo you will see that the `concurrency.group` is indeed the same for `push` and `pull_request`. You can also see that the second worfklow run cancelled the first because `concurrency.group`'s are equal. I'm guessing that you don't wan't the first worklow run to be visible at all. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be possible as of now which is a pitty: https://github.community/t/how-to-trigger-an-action-on-push-or-pull-request-but-not-both/16662/2

Comment: Actually I fell into another issue - my `build` job is required, two jobs start, then one gets cancelled. Then I end up with a branch that cannot be merged because - `Required statuses must pass before merging`

Comment: @pixel I'm not sure what your problem is but maybe [status checks](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#status-check-functions) could help you out there. I would suggest you to ask another question and add more details about it though.

Comment: my point is that when the status check is required and It runs twice and one of them is canceled then I can't merge my PR because not all required checks passed (which is really silly - one of them passed and the other one got canceled by `cancel-in-progress`)

Comment: @pixel I also had my issues with `push` and `pull_request` in the same workflow when it needs to be triggered for the same branches/paths. In the end I just stopped bothering about `pull_request` and only tried to work with `push`.. it seems like to be impossible to setup a well designed workflow because of way too many github action limitations for yet such a simple and common use case.. this counts also for various other topics related to CI/CD unfortunately.. everything basically feels like a hack

Answer (score 6):

I am using this concurrency key for my workflows in similar case:

```
group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}
```

I wanted to limit it to have single workflow running on a single branch - I am cancelling previous runs.
But this allows to have multiple runs across different branches at the same time - not sure what's your case exactly.

If you want to have one instance of workflow running across whole repository, you can just go for:

```
group: ${{ github.workflow }}
```

Comment: and what about your config when it comes to workflow events? do you have pull_request or push as well?

Comment: `group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.ref }}` this will cancel workflows on `master` (or `main`) branch and will make project look bad because of all red Xs. I find it hard to understand why GitHub doesn't offer the option to ignore certain (protected) branches.
At the same time, trying to achieve conditional `cancel-in-progress` seems like a mission impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running it like this so that each branch can run at the same time if they need to, but not more than one per branch at a time, and it works with push and pull-request:

```
jobs:
  terraform:
    concurrency:
      group: ${{ github.workflow }}-${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
```